# Trying to pull Data from Microsoft Access 2010 to C# program

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I am trying to build a program where the program pulls data from an access database. Here is the SQL Statement that I have built (which has been tested in Access and works):

```
SELECT Volunteer.LoaneeID, FirstName, LastName, SUM(HoursWorked )
FROM VOLUNTEER 
INNER JOIN PERSON 
    ON Volunteer.LoaneeID = Person.ID 
Group by FirstName, LastName, LoaneeID;
```

The issue that I am having is that sum statement above. When I run my code I get *There was an unexpected problem:"HoursWorked".*

Here is the code that I have built. I am sure it is a stupid mistake. Thanks for all the help!

```
Private void more15(string sql)
    {
        //string inputLine;
        clsQuery loanee;

        mLoanee.Clear();

        // Read the data from the specified file.

        if (File.Exists(mClientFile) == false)
        {
            ShowMessage(mClientFile + " does not exist. Please open another file.");
            return;
        }
        try
        {
            openDatabaseConnection();
            mDB.Open();
            OleDbCommand cmd;
            OleDbDataReader rdr;
            cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, mDB);
            rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (rdr.Read() == true)
            {
                loanee = new clsQuery(
                          (int)rdr["LoaneeID"],
                          (string)rdr["FirstName"],
                          (string)rdr["LastName"],
                          (int)rdr["HoursWorked"]);

                mLoanee.Add(loanee);
            }
            rdr.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ShowMessage("There was an unexpected problem: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            closeDatabaseConnection();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't give alias to sum(HoursWorked).

Change your query as below:

```
SELECT Volunteer.LoaneeID, FirstName, LastName, SUM(HoursWorked ) as HoursWorked 
FROM VOLUNTEER 
INNER JOIN PERSON 
ON Volunteer.LoaneeID = Person.ID 
Group by FirstName, LastName, LoaneeID;
```

Comment: Totally forgot about that! Thank you! I am now having issues on the C# side with casting the object

Comment: May be you should check the datatypes of the columns in the database against what you are casting them for.

Comment: Was not on the access side it was in my C# code. Changed my cls to Int32 and changed (int)rdr["HoursWorked"]); to Convert.ToInt32(rdr(["HoursWorked"]));